# What is the relation between estimator and estimate?

Tags: estimation, terminology, estimators

What is the relation between estimator and estimate?

Comment: "In statistics, an estimator is a rule for calculating an estimate of a given quantity based on observed data: thus the rule and its result (the estimate) are distinguished."  (First line of the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator ).

Comment: +1 I am upvoting this question (despite the presence of a well formulated answer on an obvious Wikipedia page) because initial attempts at answering it here have pointed to some subtleties.

Comment: @whuber, can I say the model parameters estimates are the estimator?

Comment: @loganecolss An estimator is a mathematical function. That is distinguished from the value (the estimate) it might attain for any set of data. One way to appreciate the difference is to note that certain sets of data will produce the same *estimates* of, say, the slope in a linear regression using different *estimators* (such as Maximum Likelihood or Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares, for instance). Without distinguishing estimates from the estimators used to produce those estimates, we would be unable to understand what that statement even says.

Comment: @whuber, even with one certain data set $D$, different estimator could also give different estimates, don't they?

Comment: @loganecolss Certainly.  But that fact does not address the issue you raised.

Comment: An estimator is a process to estimate a population parameter with a sample. Its result is called an estimation.

Comment: Great work Bill Huber.  Your comments is a very simple but clear and correct.  Nothing else need be said other than correcting others who still don't understand it.

Answer (score 15):

E. L. Lehmann, in his classic *Theory of Point Estimation*, answers this question on pp 1-2.

> The observations are now postulated to be the values taken on by random variables which are assumed to follow a joint probability distribution, $P$, belonging to some known class...
>
> ...let us now specialize to point estimation...suppose that $g$ is a real-valued function defined [on the stipulated class of distributions] and that we would like to know the value of $g$ [at whatever is the actual distribution in effect, $\theta$].  Unfortunately, $\theta$, and hence $g(\theta)$, is unknown.  However, the data can be used to obtain an estimate of $g(\theta)$, a value that one hopes will be close to $g(\theta)$.

In words: an *estimator* is a definite mathematical procedure that comes up with a number (the *estimate*) for any possible set of data that a particular problem could produce.  That number is intended to represent some definite numerical property ($g(\theta)$) of the data-generation process; we might call this the "estimand."

The estimator itself is *not* a random variable: it's just a mathematical function.  However, the estimate it produces is based on data which themselves are modeled as random variables.  This makes the *estimate* (thought of as depending on the data) into a random variable and *a particular estimate* for *a particular set of data* becomes a realization of that random variable.

In one (conventional) ordinary least squares formulation, the data consist of ordered pairs $(x_i, y_i)$.  The $x_i$ have been determined by the experimenter (they can be amounts of a drug administered, for example).  Each $y_i$ (a response to the drug, for instance) is assumed to come from a probability distribution that is Normal but with unknown mean $\mu_i$ and *common* variance $\sigma^2$.  Furthermore, it is assumed that the means are related to the $x_i$ via a formula $\mu_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i$.  These three parameters--$\sigma$, $\beta_0$, and $\beta_1$--determine the underlying distribution of $y_i$ for any value of $x_i$.  Therefore *any* property of that distribution can be thought of as a function of $(\sigma, \beta_0, \beta_1)$.  Examples of such properties are the intercept $\beta_0$, the slope $\beta_1$, the value of $\cos(\sigma + \beta_0^2 - \beta_1)$, or even the mean at the value $x=2$, which (according to this formulation) must be $\beta_0 + 2 \beta_1$.

In this OLS context, a *non-example* of an estimator would be a procedure to guess at the value of $y$ if $x$ were set equal to 2.  This is *not* an estimator because this value of $y$ is *random* (in a way completely separate from the randomness of the data): it is not a (definite numerical) property of the distribution, even though it is related to that distribution.  (As we just saw, though, the *expectation* of $y$ for $x=2$, equal to $\beta_0 + 2 \beta_1$, can be estimated.)

In Lehmann's formulation, almost any formula can be an estimator of almost any property.  *There is no inherent mathematical link between an estimator and an estimand.*  However, we can assess--in advance--the chance that an estimator will be reasonably close to the quantity it is intended to estimate.  Ways to do this, and how to exploit them, are the subject of estimation theory.

Comment: (+1) A very precise and detailed response.

Comment: Is not a function of a random variable itself also a random variable?

Comment: @jsk I think the distinction I was trying to make here may be clarified by considering the composition of functions $$\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}.$$ The first function is a random variable $X$; the second one (call it $t$) is termed an *estimator* here, and the *composition of the two* $$t\circ X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$$ is an "estimate" or "estimation procedure," which is--as you correctly say--a random variable.

Comment: @whuber In your post, you say "The estimator itself is not a random variable."  I attempted an edit to your post to clarify the point that you and I seem to agree on, but it seems someone rejected my edit.  Perhaps they would prefer your edit!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86023/discussion-between-whuber-and-paari-vendhan).

Comment: Consider $\mathbf{t}=t$ or $(\mathbf{t}\circ \mathbf{X}) = t$; and now that we wish to use a term for the specific realization $t$ of the r.v. $(\mathbf{t}\circ \mathbf{X})$ what would be an appropriate term for this! Further, I think both Casella and Berger sec 7.2, page 312 (Statistical Inference, 2nd Ed.), and Montgomery and Runger sec 7.1, page 221 (Applied Statistics & Probability for Engineers, 3rd Ed.) use the term estimate for $t$ instead of using it for the composition $(\mathbf{t}\circ \mathbf{X})$. Thoughts!

Comment: @whuber All theoretical statistics book I know of define estimators as random variables in a similar or identical way I did in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/628853/136579). What are your thoughts on that definition?

Comment: @statmerkur As a mathematical statement, I liked it when I read it.  But it struck me as statistically vacuous because it doesn't describe any kind of relationship between the estimator and the estimand.  Yet it very clearly answers the question!

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I agree, in the definition I use, the only relation between an estimand and a corresponding estimator is their common codomain. An estimator then is "just" a statistic (with the same codomain as the estimand) that is used for the task of estimating an estimand without specifying further requirements of that task.   
Do you think it makes sense to repost my answer as an answer to the [current thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7581/136579)?

Comment: @statmerkur Unless you were to add some thoughts about the relation between estimator and estimand, your post (in its current form) might not be considered an answer to this question.

Comment: @whuber I've added an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/629922/136579/), in case you are interested. I think it might be useful for people looking for a measure theoretic definition of the concepts.

Answer (score 10):

**In short:** an estimator is a function and an estimate is a value that summarizes an observed sample.

An **estimator** is a function that maps a random sample to the parameter estimate:

$$
\hat{\Theta}=t(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)
$$
Note that an estimator of *n* random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is a random variable $\hat{\Theta}$. For instance, an estimator is the sample mean:
$$
\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n=1}^nX_i
$$
An **estimate** $\hat{\theta}$ is the result of applying the estimator function to a lowercase observed sample $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$:

$$
\hat{\theta}=t(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)
$$
For instance, an estimate of the observed sample $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ is the sample mean:
$$
\hat{\mu}=\overline{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n=1}^nx_i
$$

Comment: estimator is a RV, while estimate is a constant?

Comment: Isn't your conclusion conflicting with @whuber's? Here you say estimator is RV, but whuber says otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I disagree with @whuber's statement "The estimator itself is not a random variable: it's just a mathematical function". A function of random variable is also a random variable. https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/128/

Answer (score 3):

It might be helpful to illustrate whuber's answer in the context of a linear regression model. Let's say you have some bivariate data and you use Ordinary Least Squares to come up with the following model:

> `Y = 6X + 1`

At this point, you can take any value of X, plug it into the model and predict the outcome, Y. In this sense, you might think of the individual components of the generic form of the model (*mX + B*) as *estimators*. The sample data (which you presumably plugged into the generic model to calculate the specific values for *m* and *B* above) provided a basis on which you could come up with *estimates* for *m* and *B* respectively.

Consistent with @whuber's points in our thread below, whatever values of *Y* a particular set of estimators generate you for are, in the context of linear regression, thought of as predicted values.

*(edited -- a few times -- to reflect the comments below)*

Comment: You have nicely defined a *predictor.*  It is subtly (but importantly) different from an estimator.  The estimator in this context is the least squares formula used to compute the parameters 1 and 6 from the data.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't mean it that way, @whuber, but I think your comment illustrates an important ambiguity in my language that I didn't notice before. The main point here is that you can think of the generic form of the equation Y = mX + B (as used above) as an estimator, whereas the particular predicted values generated by specific examples of that formula (e.g., 1 + 6X) are estimates. Let me try to edit the paragraph above to capture that distinction...

Comment: btw, I'm trying to explain this without introducing the "hat" notation that I've encountered in most textbook discussions of this concept. Perhaps that's the better route after all?

Comment: I think you have hit a nice medium between accuracy and technicality in your original answer: keep it up!  You don't need hats, but if you can manage to show how an estimator is distinguished from other, similar-looking things, that would be most helpful.  But please notice the distinction between *predicting* a value Y and *estimating* a parameter such as *m* or *b*.  Y could be interpreted as a random variable; m and b are not (except in a Bayesian setting).

Comment: indeed, a very good point in terms of parameters versus values there. Editing again...

Answer (score 1):

Let $\left(\mathcal X, \mathcal A, \left(\mathbb P_\vartheta\right)_{\vartheta \in \Theta}\right)$ be a statistical model consisting of

- a set $\mathcal X$ (the sample space),
- a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ on $\mathcal X$,
- a family of probability measures $\left(\mathbb P_\vartheta\right)_{\vartheta \in \Theta}$ on $\mathcal A$ with
- index set $\Theta$ (the parameter space) of cardinality bigger than one.

Let $(\Sigma, \mathcal S)$ be another event space, i.e., a measurable space.

Let $\tau: \Theta \to \Sigma$ be any function, whose value at $\vartheta \in \Theta$ is to be estimated.

Then, an *estimator* $T$ of the *estimand* $\tau$ is defined to be any [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition) from $(\mathcal X, \mathcal A)$ to $(\Sigma, \mathcal S)$.
For any $x \in \mathcal X$, the realization $T(x)$ is called the corresponding *estimate*.

Clearly, we want an estimate to be "close" to its estimand at any true (but unknown) parameter value $\vartheta \in \Theta$. But in the definitions this is not formalized beyond the common codomain of estimands and their estimators  to avoid unnecessary narrowing of the concepts.

---

Unfortunately, some people use the term estimate for both estimators and estimates (as defined above). For example, Cox and Hinkley write the following in *Theoretical Statistics* on page 252:

> Suppose that we have a scalar parameter $\theta$, and let $T$ be a
> statistic and $t$ its observed value. When estimating $\theta$, $T$ is
> sometimes called an *estimator*, $t$ an *estimate*; we shall use the
> single term estimate.

---

**References**

- Cox, D. R., & Hinkley, D. V. (1974). *Theoretical statistics*. Chapman & Hall.
- Georgii, H.-O. (2013). *Stochastics: Introduction to probability and statistics* (E. Baake & M. Ortgiese, Trans.). Walter de Gruyter.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you received some data, and you had some observed variable called theta. Now your data can be from a distribution of data, for this distribution, there is a corresponding value of theta that you infer which is a random variable. You can use the MAP or mean for calculating the estimate of this random variable whenever the distribution of your data changes. So the random variable theta is known as an **estimate**, a single value of the unobserved variable for a particular type of data.

While estimator is your data, which is also a random variable. For different types of distributions you have different types of data and thus you have a different estimate and thus this corresponding random variable is called the **estimator**.