# Notation for estimator in Murphy's Machine Learning (Chapter 6)

Tags: machine-learning, estimators, notation

I'm confused with the notation for estimators in Chapter 6 of Murphy's "Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective":

In section 6.2, he initially refers to an estimator as $\delta$ in the beginning of the section.

> ...is computed by applying an estimator $\delta$ to some data D, so $\hat{\theta} = \delta(D)$.

Later in that paragraph, he refers to the estimator as the $\hat{\theta}(\cdot)$ function.

> Now apply the estimator $\hat{\theta}(\cdot)$ to each D...

Then in section 6.2.1, he says the estimator is equal to a function f().

> We could then compute our estimator from each sample, $\hat{\theta^s} = f(x_{1:N}^s)$ and...

My question is why are there three different notations for the estimator? Are they all the same?

Comment: This question appears to be one of speculative psychology: it invites us to guess the intentions of the author.  Is there any statistical content to your question?

Comment: @whuber My hope was that it wasn't a question of guessing what's in the authors head but that there was a known difference between the notations used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no general difference between those notations. As *whuber* notices, we could speculate why the author used different notation in different places for apparently the same thing, but this would be a guessing game since it was not stated in the text.

The main distinction is between *estimator* and *estimate* and is described [in this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7608/35989):

> an *estimator* is a definite mathematical procedure that comes up with
>   a number (the *estimate*) for any possible set of data that a
>   particular problem could produce

So estimator is a function that takes data as input and returns an estimate. Initially Kevin Murphy uses $\hat \theta$ (and later $\hat{\theta^s}$) to denote the estimate and $\delta(\cdot)$ to denote estimator, but later on he uses also $\hat\theta(\cdot)$ or $f(\cdot)$, but he does not give any distinction between the functions, so it seems that in all the cases he simply means *some* function. This is apparent if you check the section 6.2.1 where once he writes $\hat{\theta^s} = f(x_{1:N}^s)$ so few lines later uses $\hat{\theta^s} = \hat\theta(x_{1:N}^s)$, while in both cases referring to estimates based on bootstrap samples $x_i^s$.

Notice that [similar ambiguity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633597/what-does-y-yx-mean#) may appear in general mathematical notation where some authors write $y(x) = \text{{function body}}$ interchangeably with $y = \text{{function body}}$ dropping the $x$ in brackets to simplify the notation. Yes, if used like this it may be confusing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This clears up my concerns!