# Estimation vs Optimization

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, optimization, terminology

I am finding it difficult to differentiate Estimation methods from Optimization methods in the context of Machine Learning. Both are used for calculating the parameters of our model so how are they any different? Is any one of them the subset of the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Optimization** is a general term for finding the maximum, or minimum, of some function. **Estimation** is a statistical term for finding some [estimate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/what-is-the-relation-between-estimator-and-estimate) of unknown parameter, given some data. This can be done using optimization methods, e.g. by [maximizing the likelihood function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms), or minimizing a loss function. So optimization is broader, as you can use it without data, just by finding the maximum of some abstract function, while estimation has a clear statistical scope.
Optimization can be used for estimation, but you can also use methods not based on optimization for estimation.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand "optimization is broader". Does it mean that estimation is a subset of optimization? Of course, there are a lot of optimization problems that are not about estimation. However, are all estimation problems optimization problems? For example, the method of moments for estimation doesn't seem to be constructed as an optimization method.

Comment: NO, there are estimation methods which do not use optimization, like method of moments or bayes methods